# How to only allow adding new entries to realtime database?

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-security

I have a collection of contacts (subscribers):

```
{
    "contacts": {
        "-LHi-8bIG4xaZADdc9mf": {
            "name": "John Doe",
            "email": "example@example.com"
        },
        "-LHi-PL2HORYJTXB2MjE": {
            "name": "Jane Doe",
            "email": "example@example.com"
        }
    }
}
```

I now need a security rule to allow anonymous users adding new entries, but not reading or updating existing ones.

I currently use this rule, but it seems to also allow updating existing entries as well as overwriting the entire "contacts" collection:

```
{
    "rules": {
        "contacts": {
            ".read": false,
            ".write": "newData.exists()"
        }
    }
}
```

I also tried `!data.exists()` but this seems to restrict write access at all.

Comment: Please include your datastructure as it is in firebase database and the code you are using to write.

Comment: I've updated the collection above to actually match the json export from firebase. I only tested via simulator, since I don't have access to the client yet. Both "writes" to `contacts` and `contacts/-LHi-8bIG4xaZADdc9mf` succeed or fail according to above rules.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your current rules are for the entire contacts node. So if any data exists there you won't be able to add anything else.

What you need to do is add an extra layer using a [wildcard](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/security/securing-data#using_variables_to_capture_path_segments) in your rules like this:

```
{
    "rules": {
        "contacts": {
            // This is the wildcard that represents the user uid 
            "$user_id": {
              ".read": false,
              ".write": "!data.exists()"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Also check out the docs about [existing data vs new data](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/security/securing-data#existing_data_vs_new_data).

Comment: Great, I'll try it tomorrow and accept your answer if everything works well with the client. It doesn't allow me to write to `/contacts` in the simulator. Guess you can't simulate a POST request there.

Comment: @sboesch You have to make sure you are writing to the correct location. With these rules you can't write directly to `/contacts`, you have to write one lvl deeper. And you can actually get rid of the read rule because the default already is false.